# ListView is only Displaying Text and Not Images

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, android-arrayadapter

I'm attempting to create a listView that displays text and an image under the text. I created my own custom adapter so I can perform such a task. However, when i create my app it only displays a textView and completely skips the imageView. What can I do to make the image appear? I assume something might be wrong in my custom adapter class but i'm not exactly sure what it could be as i believe everything else should be correct.

**Please note that I am using Picasso to load and display the images**

My MainActivity AsyncTask Class

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String content = HttpManager.getData(params[0]);
        return content;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        hideDialog();
        String parseResult = InfoJSONResultParser.parseFeed(result);

        importerArray = OrderInformationParser.orderParser(result);



        if (parseResult.equals("ok")) {
            //Returns the Array with the JSON info already parsed.

            String[] descriptionArray = OrderInformationParser.orderParser(result);
            String[] photoArray = PhotoParser.photoParser(result);
            List<Bean> myList = new ArrayList<>();
            list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.orderListView);

            for(int i = 0; i < descriptionArray.length;i++) {
                Bean bean = new Bean();
                bean.setText(descriptionArray[i]);
                bean.setUrl(photoArray[i]);
                myList.add(bean);
                MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(OrdersActivity.this, myList);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

        } else {
            findViewById(R.id.nullOrders).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

}
```

My Custom Array Adapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private List<Bean> mList;

public MyAdapter(Context context,List<Bean> list){
    mContext=context;
    mList=list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    //use converview recycle
    if(convertView==null){
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.content_orders, parent, false);
        holder.textView= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        holder.imageView= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    //set text and url
    holder.textView.setText(mList.get(position).getText());
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(mList.get(position).getUrl()).into(holder.imageView);

    return convertView;
}

class ViewHolder{
    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;

}
}
```

My GetterAndSetterClass (Bean)

```
public class Bean {
String text;
String url;

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}
}
```

My Content XML File surrounded by a RelativeLayout

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nullOrders"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/no_orders_message"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:visibility="gone" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"/>
```

My Activity XML File where the listView is contained

```
<ListView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/orderListView"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:dividerHeight="2dp"/>
```

Comment: First you need to verify that the `photoArray` is properly filled up. After that trace the execution by debugging to see where it stops going according to plan. After that edit the question. That'd be my suggestion.

Comment: Won't fix your issue, but move the adapter creation and setting outside of the loop - you can create it after your list has been fully populated.

Comment: Also not a fix (but could be). Move away from List Views and use RecyclerView. Solid example here: https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Comment: did you open INTERNET permission of mainifest.xml?

Comment: @Cgx My manifest file has permissions for internet and to get network status.